# Finding the limits of integration for a triple integral where a tetrahedron is bounded by a plane?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given:
$$ \iiint\limits_{Q}\, f(x,y,z)\, dV$$

Such that $Q$ is a tetrahedron, bounded by the plane $3x-5y-2z = 30$.

Write the iterated triple integral in the order of integration dx, dz, dy.

My approach:
$$3x-5y-2z = 30$$
$$\frac{1}{30} (3x-5y-2z) = 1$$
$$\frac{x}{10} - \frac{y}{6} - \frac{z}{15} = 1$$

(a, 0, 0), (0, b, 0), (0, 0, c)

(10, 0, 0), (0, -6, 0), (0, 0, -15)

$$ \int_{0}^{\frac{3x}{5} - 6} \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2} (3 x - 5 (6 + y))}  \int_{0}^{10}\, dx\, dz\, dy $$

This gives: $\frac{9}{2} (x - 10)^2$ which is wrong.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the answer $150$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw the region it helps!

From the yz-trace I get:
$$z = -\frac{5}{2}y - 15$$

$$\int_{-6}^{0}\int_{-\frac{5}{2}y - 15}^{0}\int_{0}^{\frac{30+5y+2z}{3}} \, f(x,y,y)\, dx\, dz\, dy$$

The bounds of the outermost integral are obtained from the the trace as well.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \int_{0}^{6} \int_{0}^{\frac{-30-5y}{2}}  \int_{0}^{\frac{30+5y+2z}{3}}\, dx\, dz\, dy $$     because according to your order of integration your integration should look like                                       $$ \int_{0}^{a} \int_{0}^{f_2(z)}  \int_{0}^{f_1(y,z)}\, dx\, dz\, dy $$